# how can i solve the problem with slash im discord.js?

Tags: javascript, discord.js, bots

my bot worked until yesterday, but I updated it and put some new commands and now this error appears
,when I click for my bot to start this error appears: Reason: DiscordAPIError[50035]: Invalid Form Body
2.options[0].type[NUMBER_TYPE_COERCE]: Value "integer" is not int.
and this appears in all bot slashed commands

here the codes of one of the bot screens:

```
const { getVoiceConnection } = require("@discordjs/voice");
module.exports = {
name: "volume",
description: "Changes the Volume of the Music",
options: [
{
  name: "volume",
  description: "Then Volume you want to set",
  type: "INTEGER",
  required: true,
},
],
run: async (client, interaction, args, prefix) => {
if (!interaction.member.voice.channelId)
  return interaction
    .reply({
      ephemeral: true,
      content: " **Please join a Voice-Channel first!**",
    })
    .catch(() => null);
// get an old connection
const oldConnection = getVoiceConnection(interaction.guild.id);
if (!oldConnection)
  return interaction.reply({
    ephemeral: true,
    content: " **I'm not connected somewhere!**",
  });
if (
  oldConnection &&
  oldConnection.joinConfig.channelId != interaction.member.voice.channelId
)
  return interaction
    .reply({
      ephemeral: true,
      content: " **We are not in the same Voice-Channel**!",
    })
    .catch(() => null);

const queue = client.queues.get(interaction.guild.id); // get the queue
if (!queue) {
  return interaction.reply({
    ephemeral: true,
    content: ` **Nothing playing right now**`,
  });
}
if (
  !args[0] ||
  isNaN(args[0]) ||
  Number(args[0]) < 1 ||
  Number(args[0]) > 150
)
  return interaction
    .reply({
      ephemeral: true,
      content: ` **No __valid__ Volume between 1 and 100 % provided!** Usage: \`${prefix}volume 25\``,
    })
    .catch(() => null);
const volume = Number(args[0]);
queue.volume = volume;

// change the volume
oldConnection.state.subscription.player.state.resource.volume.setVolume(
  volume / 100
);

return interaction
  .reply({
    ephemeral: false,
    content: ` **Successfully changed the Volume to \`${volume}%\`**`,
  })
  .catch(() => null);
  },
  };
```

Comment: What version of discord.js do you have? Type `npm list discord.js` in your terminal that you run the bot from.

Comment: my discord version is discord.js@14.1.2

Comment: did you update from v13?

Comment: yes my last version is v13

Comment: you can't just update from 13 to 14, it's a breaking change. you can follow [this guide on how to upgrade to v14](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v14.html#before-you-start)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the enums in v14. In this case, [`ApplicationCommandOptionType`](https://discord-api-types.dev/api/discord-api-types-v10/enum/ApplicationCommandOptionType)

```js
const { ApplicationCommandOptionType } = require("discord.js")
// ...
  {
    // ...
    type: ApplicationCommandOptionType.Integer
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have went from v13 to v14 - this is a breaking change. Discord.js implemented a lot of changes that change the way that your bot is developed and code from previous versions in incompatible and requires you to upgrade the code itself.

You can view this page on [Upgrading from v13 to v14](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v14.html#before-you-start).